# Can I get original message after response

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

Can you help me with spring integration.

I have Integration flow for send post request to other system with http.

Can I get original message after sending it, because I wanna do other operations on success and error.

ErrorHandler just has HttpClientResponse, but response body is empty and I need originalMessage to handle this situation.

The same situation with success response. I don't have original message information to do next operation.

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow incChannel(HeaderEnricher enrichHeaders,
                                      HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler notifyOnArrival) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("send_notify_to")
                .transform(enrichHeaders)
                .handle(notifyOnArrival)
                .channel("save_success_status_original")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public HeaderEnricher enrichHeaders() {
        Map<String, ? extends HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>> headersToAdd =
                Collections.singletonMap("Content-Type", new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor<>(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
        HeaderEnricher enricher = new HeaderEnricher(headersToAdd);
        return enricher;
    }

    @Bean
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler notifyOnArrival(@Value("${uri}") String uri,
                                                          MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter) {

        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler =
                new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(uri + "/api/notify");
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        handler.setExpectReply(false);
        handler.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(messageConverter));
        return handler;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.handle(notifyOnArrival)` is just a Service Activator with all the state carrying from the request to reply. Only what we need is to ensure that we really provide that state. the best place to keep a state in the context of the message is to store the request message into headers and then restore it from there in the reply afterward or from the `ErrorMessage`.

```
headersToAdd.put("originalMesasge", new ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor("#root", Message.class));
```

So, you add that `originalMesasge` from the request message and this one is going to be copying by the Service Activator logic into the reply message.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I see. But it start to work only with reply
 handler.setExpectReply(false);   should be true

Comment: You probably need to see if you can add an expression advice to the endpoint for your REST call: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: I change HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler  to HTTP builder initialization, but it init with expectedReply(false), and this method is protected and I can't call it. Why it made so?